# Next JS 13.4 appDir - MUI Compiled / (home-page) in 8.2s (2731 modules)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, material-ui, next.js13

I am using "@mui/material": "5.14.13" and "next": "13.5.4" but I noticed that in development and also build is slow, this is a screenshot that it loads 2728 modules just in homepage:

[image: next js mui]

This is not good, does someone have any solution for this. I implemented mui in next js from this documentation: [MUI DOC](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/next-js-app-router/)

I tried flatten import example from this:

import { Box } from "@mui/material";

to this:

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

This reduces first load js but again its not how it should be, again it loads 2728 modules.